# Select top field based on ordering of another field

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Sorry if the title is hard to understand -- I'm not quite sure how to describe what I want to do. Let's say I have this table. test1 and test2 are int columns, whereas test3 is a string/varchar:

```
test1 | test2 | test3
1       1       one
1       2       two
1       3       three
1       4       four
2       10      ten
2       11      eleven
2       12      twelve
3       101     one hundred one
3       104     one hundred four
3       107     one hundred seven
```

I am trying to figure out the select query that will return the top test3 for each test1, where the ordering is done based on the value in test2. In other words, I am trying to find the query that will return this:

```
test1 | test3
1       four
2       twelve
3       one hundred seven
```

It'd be really great if the solution could work on both MS SQL Server (2005 and 2008) and MS Access (2007 and 2010).

Comment: I believe you wanted `1, four` instead, right?

Answer (score 2):

A Lowest common denominator answer.

```
SELECT yourtable.test1, yourtable.test3
FROM yourtable
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT test1, MAX(test2) AS test_2
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY test1
) t
ON t.test1 =  yourtable.test1 AND t.test_2 =  yourtable.test2
```

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT  test1, test3
FROM    (
        SELECT  test1, test3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test1 ORDER BY test2 DESC) AS rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

or

```
SELECT  test1, test3
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT test1
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                test3
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.test1 = md.test1
        ORDER BY
                mi.test2 DESC
        ) mt
```

Each of these methods can be more efficient than another, depending on your data distribution.

This article may be of interest to you:

- [**SQL Server: Selecting records holding group-wise maximum**](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/30/sql-server-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum/)